# Return receipts in PHP (pop3 and imap)

Tags: php, email

Im writing small module to manage emails. One of important functionality in my system will have possibility to return receipt (or acknowledgement of receipt).

I have problem with it because I don't know which header I should use that I want return-receipts (Now in POP3 and IMAP I set **X-Confirm-Reading-To:**). Also I don't know how I can change header or signed message that I returned-receipt in IMAP (against situation that system will ask about return receipts every time - I want to change header that I sended message or I didn't want send. In POP3 it is easy because I just change information in database).

Comment: Return receipts are not a standard component of email, they're proprietary client-specific extensions. Do you have any particular client you're targeting?

Comment: I dont have any particular client (I test system using thunderbird, gmail and outlook)